# What is the delta parameter in $\tt scal2freq$?

Tags: matlab, wavelet

I am running complex morlet (`cmor1-1.5`) wavelet transform. I want to have the transformation for the range of $[1,150]\textrm{ Hz}$ with a step of $1\textrm{ Hz}$.
I want to use `scal2freq` Matlab function to convert scales to pseudo frequencies but I don`'t know how to define the delta.

Answer (score 1):

The delta argument in the scal2freq MATLAB function is the sampling period that relates to the data sampling frequency (i.e. delta = 1/Fs).  A good description of this function can be found here: http://au.mathworks.com/help/wavelet/ref/scal2frq.html it also includes an example including how to calculate and define the delta argument.  I hope this helps!

Comment: @pinar, was I able to answer your question?